# comparing string related attributes in python

Tags: python, string, compare

To compare two strings I am using difflib which work well for me.
However, I would like to compare the attributes of the two strings I am comparing.
E.g. string 1 is "This *is* **L**ine 1" and string 2 is "This **is** *L*ine 2"
I want to compare if the font attributes like Bold, Italics, font name, font size, etc. are also the same between the two strings.

lets assume that every unique combination of the 4 attributes mentioned above can be codified as F1, F2, etc. I end up with a list of tuples
e.g. String 1 = [(T, F1), (h, F1), (i, F1), (s, F1), ( ,F1), (i,F2), (s,F2),.......]
where F0, F1, F2 are some combination of Bold, Italics, Font name and Font size

Without actually looping through every character in the list, is there a faster way to compare these attributes? Is there another way I can store the attributes that will make comparison easier?

Thanks.

Comment: Strings don't have formatting. Are you referring to strings containing HTML? If so, please include the actual strings.

Comment: The text is extracted from a PDF file and the extractor gives both the text and the text attributes.